# Flutter Async: Future.wait() constantly returning null

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, flutter-futurebuilder

For some reason, `Future.wait()` is constantly returning `null`. I'm not completely certain I am using it correctly.

For context, I have a collection of `posts` in Firebase. For each post, I can extract the `userID` assigned to it, then for each post individually I use the `userID` of the poster to grab the `username` for display purposes. I grab the `Post` from a snapshot:

```dart
static Future<Post> fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> doc) async {
    final _documentId = doc.id;
    final _title = doc.get('title');
    final _text = doc.get('text');
    final _createdOn = doc.get('createdOn');
    final _userID = doc.get('userID');

    final userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_userID).get();
    final username = userDoc.get("username");

    return Post(documentId: _documentId, title: _title, text: _text, createdOn: _createdOn, username: username);
  }
```

and the extraction of `posts` occurs in a `getPosts()` function elsewhere:

```dart
Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    QuerySnapshot posts = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').get();

    final allData = posts.docs.map(
            (doc) async => await Post.fromSnapshot(doc)
    ).toList();

    print(allData);                             // [Instance of 'Future<Post>', Instance of 'Future<Post>', Instance of 'Future<Post>']

    final futurePosts = Future.wait(allData);
    print(futurePosts);                         // Instance of 'Future<List<Post>>'

    // why does this always return null?
    return futurePosts;
  }
```

the problem is it has to be async to extract the posts but also to get the username, meaning it returns a future list of future posts. I want to pass the result of `getPosts()` to a `FutureBuilder`, so I need a `Future List` of posts, and to not make all the posts `Future` I use `Future.wait` - but that always seems to return null. Essentially, I am mapping each post in the snapshot to its own `Post` item, where in the constructor it needs to run a further `async` call to extract the `username`. Am I missing something?

Note: even making the `Future.wait()` `await` returns `null`, it just also doesn't return a `List` of type `Future` so I can't use it in the `FutureBuilder` either.

Edit 1:
It turns out that `futurePosts` is actually an `Instance of 'Future<List<Post>>'`, but when accessing the data within the FutureBuilder, `snapshot.data` is `null`:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Feed'),
    ),
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getPosts(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            return postsToColumn(context, snapshot.data as List<Post>);
          }
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You can use `Future.value(allData)`

Comment: What's the output of this: print(allData);?

Comment: To me it seems impossible that it returns null. `Future.wait` never returns null. At the very least it returns a future that returns an empty list. If `getPosts` would be able to return null the compiler would already complain also  and you couldn't even run your app. What do you exactly mean with "it returns null"? because that simply is impossible

Comment: @krumpli it prints `[Instance of 'Future<Post>', Instance of 'Future<Post>', Instance of 'Future<Post>']`

Comment: @IvoBeckers you are actually right, if I `print(futurePosts)` I get `Instance of 'Future<List<Post>>'`. The `null` appears to actually come in the `FutureBuilder` itself, when I `print(snapshot.data)`, so it appears as if the `snapshot` itself is the issue? Perhaps I'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: I've edited the question by adding comments to the code to show the output of the `print` statements, and also included the `FutureBuilder` code itself so somone could see why `snapshot.data` might be `null`.

Comment: My guess is that `Post.fromSnapshot(doc)` maybe throws an error. Why is hard to say. But if it does then it should be visible in logcat/console

Comment: @IvoBeckers does that make sense? It's goes past the `Post.fromSnapshot(doc)` and successfully creates the `Future<List<Post>>`, so doesn't that mean that part is fine? Am I perhaps trying to extract `snapshot.data` too soon?

Comment: I have no idea actually. you could try to check on `if (snapshot.hasData)` instead of `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)`  , I don't know if that helps. I'm also out of ideas now

Comment: Thanks @IvoBeckers, you gave me an idea, and I've sorted the issue out and posted an answer lining it out. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lots of thanks to @IvoBeckers for helping me pin this down. It turns out, the `snapshot` actually did have an error, as they said, but this doesn't get printed unless you print it explicitly:

```dart
if (snapshot.hasError) {
  print(snapshot.error.toString());
}
```

And the error is

```
Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist
```

So it turns out that not every `User` has a corresponding entry in the `users` collection with its `username`, which sounds like something I should have checked before, but I thought such an error would be printed out in the console. Once I updated the `users` collection, it worked perfectly.